Echo not printing CDATA tags in Wordpress
I am creating a RSS feed in WordPress. In my functions.php, I have
$content = htmlentities(strip_tags(get_the_content()), ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
echo '<description><![CDATA[' . $content . ']]></description>';
But the output is:
<description> Lorem Ipsum </description>
Where as it is expected to be:
<description><![CDATA[ Lorem Ipsum  ]]></description
I saw of editing the post-template.php, here is mine

I tried commenting in my post-template.php still I am facing the issue
I am using Bitnami Lightsail WP

Are you viewing the rendered output in your browser, or looking at the raw source (such as with view source)?

Just to be clear, you know that any changes to core file might be lost during an upgrade, and you are only doing this for testing purposes?

Yes, its just for testing purposes
